# Can I create work profiles for multiple companies on one device?

Tags: android-management-api

By creating a work profile for general users, we plan to provide EMM service by separating it from personal space.

Assume that EMM services are provided to companies A and B.
A user (user1) wants to visit companies A and B in turn.

User1 visits Company A and creates a work profile.

Next, when user1 visits Company B, the work profile of Company A applied to the existing user's mobile phone is deleted.
Do I need to reinstall Company B's work profile?

Is it possible to apply both the work profiles of companies A and B to user1's device?

Answer (score 1):

No, only one work profile can be created on one device. You may refer to this [link](https://support.google.com/work/android/thread/166634768?hl=en&msgid=166638746) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have 1 work profile per Android personal user account, but you can have multiple user accounts so you *should* be able to have multiple work profiles, but the notifications across the accounts may be limited as the "active" account gets the vast majority of the system processing rights, and the permissions for other accounts to send notifications might be tricky.

I think GrapheneOS has improved the notifications experience for multiple users, but it still might not be perfect when you throw work profiles into the mix.